# Best practices on where to place method querying two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a method written which queries model A, and based on the results updates/creates rows on model B. Should this be added to model A or model B?

In the past I've been placing methods in the model being changed, however am not sure if this is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you split your code into two so that one method will get the queries ModelA and another method will create/update the attributes of ModelB, and from ModelA call ModelB method.

```
# ModelA
def method_in_model_a
  result = ModelA.where(....)
  ModelB.method_in_modelb(result)
end

# ModelB
def self.method_in_model_b(result)
  # code to create/update this model object
end
```